# Knockout JS How to Access a Value from Second View Model / Binding

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am new to Knockout JS and think it is great. The documentation is great but I cannot seem to use it to solve my current problem.

**The Summary of my Code**

I have two viewmodels represented by two js scripts. They are unified in a parent js file. The save button's event is outside
both foreach binders. I can save all data in the details foreach.

**My Problem**

I need to be able to include the value from the contacts foreach binder with the values from the details foreach binder.

**What I have tried**

I have tried accessig the data from both viewmodels from the parent viewmodel and sending the POST request to the controller from there but the observeableArrays show undefined.

**Create.CSHTML (Using MVC5 no razor)**

```
     <div id="container1" data-bind="foreach: contacts">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: contactname" />
     </div>
     <div data-bind="foreach: details" class="card-body">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: itemValue" />
     </div>
      The save is outside of both foreach binders
      <div class="card-footer">
        <button type="button" data-bind="click: $root.save" class="btn 
           btn-success">Send Notification</button>
      </div>

<script src="~/Scripts/ViewScripts/ParentVM.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ViewScripts/ViewModel1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ViewScripts/ViewModel2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**ViewModel1**

```
    var ViewModel1 = function (contacts) {
        var self = this;
    
        self.contacts = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contacts, function (contact) {
            return {
                contactName: contact.contactName
            };
        }));
    }
```

**ViewModel2**

```
    var ViewModel2 = function (details) {
        var self = this;
       self.details = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(details, function (detail) {
            return {
                itemNumber: detail.itemValue
           };
        }));
    }

self.save = function () {
 
        $.ajax({
            url: baseURI,
            type: "POST",
            data: ko.toJSON(self.details),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                window.location.href = "/Home/Create/";
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                window.location.href = "/Homel/Create/";
            }
        });
    };
```

**ParentViewModel**

```
var VM1;
var VM2;

var initialContactInfo = [
    {
        contactPhone: ""
    }
]

var initialForm = [
  {
     itemValue: ""
   ]
}

    $(document).ready(function () {
    
        if ($.isEmptyObject(VM1)) {
            ArnMasterData = new ViewModel1(initialContactInfo);
            ko.applyBindings(VM1, document.getElementById("container1"));
        }
    
        if ($.isEmptyObject(VM2)) {
            VM2 = new ViewModel2(initialForm);
            ko.applyBindings(VM2, document.getElementById("container2"));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your question is very similar to this example:  http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections.  And to make ajax requests, this example:  http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, I do not see anything on SO similiar to this. If you feel like posting this I'll accept it.

Comment: Perhaps is better that you delete this question.  I have only shown you where the information you need to solve your question is, but I have not really answered it. :-)

Comment: I'll lave it up for a bit for aesthetic purposes.

Comment: Ok, then you could add your own answer with your solution.  I only provided links, not a solution. :-)